# Plural or singular: "Long live Europe" or "Long lives Europe"

Tags: verbs, nouns, grammatical-number

Is *Europe* is a singular or plural noun?

Ursula von der Leyen said in an EU speech "long **live** Europe" instead of "long **lives** Europe".

A quick search turn up sites like [this](https://www.isplural.com/plural_singular/europe), which simply says "Singular", which is inconsistent with the usage above, and provides no explanation.

Comment: This question might be relevant https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154482/is-long-live-our-noble-queen-inverted-is-it-imperative

Comment: "Long live Europe" is a wish or a hope about the future.  Here, "live" is not the indicative present tense third-person singular, so we know it is something else.  "Long lives Europe", or in more conventional word-order "Europe lives long", could be a statement about history up to now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [History of "X is dead. Long live X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35589/history-of-x-is-dead-long-live-x)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a matter of singular or plural it's about the [mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood); "long live [whatever]" expresses a desire for the future, "long lives [whatever]" would be a statement of the present state of affairs, if anyone said it that way. The origin of the phrase "long live Europe" is probably *le roi est mort, vive le roi* or the king is dead, long live the king, the first king being the dead Charles VI and the second his son who became Charles VII from that moment on but the sentiment is probably much older.

Comment: The question is off-topic in my opinion (ELL or duplicate) so I have not answered it, but your answer is incorrect. It is not a question of tense, it is a question of mood. Here "live" is present subjunctive — one of the relatively few remaining uses of the subjunctive in English.

Comment: @David I'd have said it's a furture-invocative statement since the phraseology has a French, not English, origin.

Comment: “God save our gracious queen, Long live our noble queen…” Not English?

Comment: @David Not originally, it comes from the Norman French phrase _le roi est mort, vive le roi_; the king is dead, long live the king, first used in 1422, before modern English was being spoken anywhere.

Comment: @Ash: It's still the English subjunctive, and was originally a direct translation of the [French subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vive,_viva,_and_vivat), translated back when the subjunctive was widely used in English.

Comment: @Ash It’s much older than 1422, and it doesn’t originate in French. That’s just a very well-known example of the construction. Classical Latin had many examples of _viva(n)t X_, for example. There is no future involved (I don’t know what exactly you mean by ‘future-invocative’); it is a simple present subjunctive used to stand in for a third-person imperative (as is also the case in both the French and Latin version; this is often called a _jussive subjunctive_).

Comment: @PeterShor It's Optative (not invocative, my apologies), and that's not a mood/tense in English okay I stand corrected.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was thinking of "Optative" and typing too fast.

Comment: @Ash The optative is used for similar purposes in languages that have it, such as Ancient Greek and Sanskrit (though those also have true third-person imperatives and would probably be equally likely to use those instead). The Latin subjunctive historically comes from a merger of the old subjunctive and optative, so it is halfway optative, in a way.

Comment: Phew, that's a relief. I thought there was something grammatical called the future invocative that I'd never heard of. Can't find anything googling. Long live the subjunctive! (Although I doubt it.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've always thought frozen forms like *Devil take the hindmost!* to be as close to a third-person imperative as English is apt to see without adding *let* or *may*. Their absence is what weirds people out, which helps illustrate that this is no longer productive.