# How did "that" get substituted for "who" or "whom" in common usage?

Tags: whom, who

I am curious at the ubiquitous use of "that"--rather than "who," or "whom"--when referring to a person.  Wondering how it happened that people became equated with objects.
    Some magazines still use "who" and "whom," but I have read "that" many times in print and almost always hear it used in everyday conversation.

Comment: Some examples, please!!

Comment: You can search "relative pronoun that" and read when it can replace who/whom/which and when it can't. Please include your own research when asking a question here. Good luck.

Comment: The point clearly stated in both title and question was to ask how “that” could reasonably be substituted for “who” or “whom” when referring to people, as opposed to things.
I thought JBright was very clearly asking specifically why anyone even accepted, let alone wanted to use “the man who came to dinner…”. “The monster that came to dinner…” would show a correct use of “that”; “the man who came to dinner…” the correct term for a man.
How is any of the rest, bar AnderssonPublishing’s support for JBright, relevant, please?

Answer (score 3):

There is a fairly widespread analysis according to which "that" in restrictive relative clauses is not a relative pronoun, but is rather a clause introducer.  See, for instance McCawley *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*.  In this case, use of "that" rather than a wh-pronoun has nothing to do with somehow objectifying people.

Elsewhere, "that" introduces subordinate clauses -- in noun complements, such as "the fact that he disappeared", and in verb complements, such as "know that he disappeared".  And unlike a real relative pronoun, "that" in a relative clause always comes at the beginning of the clause -- compare "the book about which he talked" with *"the book about that he talked".

Answer (score 2):

***[That](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=that)***  as a pronoun is an old usage that dates back to Old English:

> - Old English þæt, "that, so that, after that," ***neuter singular demonstrative pronoun ("A Man's a Man for a' that"), relative pronoun ("O thou that hearest prayer")***.....
> - From Proto-Germanic *that, from PIE *tod-, extended form of demonstrative pronominal base -to-.  ***With the breakdown of the grammatical gender system, it came to be used in Middle English and Modern English for all genders.***

Etymonline

Answer (score 1):

The *that* you refer to is apparently the *that* of relative clauses, which alternates with *who/which*

- *the man [that/who came to dinner]* (either *that* or *wh-* is required for a subject pronoun)
- *the car [(that/which) he came in]* (*that* and *wh-* are optional as non-subjects)

This *that* is not a demonstrative pronoun, and does not refer to a neuter noun; it's [a complementizer that introduces a tensed subordinate clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73368/15299), and it's used in English
also to mark subject and object complement clauses:

- *[That he has never seen that before] surprises her*  (*that* is required for a subject clause)
- *I think [(that) he has never seen that before]* (*that* is optional for non-subjects)

*That* used to appear even with tensed adverb clauses, and still does in some dialects, so that some people say

- *before **that** we set up the tent*

instead of

- *before we set up the tent*

So you don't need to worry so much about *that*. There's nothing wrong with that *that*.

Answer (score -2):

I always fix this when I run across it in editing jobs. I'm with you, JBright, there is a difference and we should use precision in language. I don't think a horse is a who and I don't think a woman is a that.