# Appositive or Complement?

Tags: clauses, that, complements, appositives

> The way **(that) he eats** amuses me.
>
> I found the way **(that) leads out of here**.
>
> I love ice-cream in the same way **(that) I love my mom**.

1) The part of speech of the word *that* is conjunction in all three sentences?

2) Are all three parts in bold *that-clauses/noun clauses*? The second one seems to be missing a subject to qualify as a clause.

3) The parts in bold, are they appositives or complements? If the latter, are they subject or object complements?

Comment: These are NOT appositives.  "That" serves as a subordinating conjunction on all of these sentences. They won't naturally be subject or object complements UNLESS their function serves as a noun.  If they serve as adjectival or adverbial complements they won't be objective complements.

Comment: These are all relative clauses modifying _way_. _How_ can't be used as a relative pronoun (*_the way how he did it_), but it can be deleted, or _that_ can be used instead (_the way he did it, the way that he did it_). But since _way_ is always used in this construction, the sense can be easily reconstructed. Much the same is true of _why_ -- it **can** be used to head a relative clause, but only if it modifies the word _reason_.

Comment: @JohnLawler So _that_ is a relative pronoun here and not a conjunction? Also can you elaborate on why its not an appositive or complement here?

Comment: It's a relative clause, so it's not an appositive; I wouldn't call them complements, because I only use that term for noun clauses. The question of whether _that_ in relative clauses is a relative pronoun or not has vexed people for ages. It's in the final stages of turning into one. _That_ used to be a complementizer (not a conjunction) introducing tensed subordinate clauses. It still works that way for complements, and occasionally for adverbials; in relatives it's been conflated with the relative pronoun, and now is complementary with the _wh_-words. If it walks like a pronoun, ...

Comment: See [this answer for an example](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73368/15299) of complementizer _that_ with adverb clauses.

Comment: @JohnLawler You said you only reserve the term complements for noun clauses, yet in the link above (third bullet point) it says _Adjective clause (NP complement)_, so I'm confused. I admit I still cannot fully grasp the difference between NP complement vs. relative clauses, apart from the fact that the former has a _picture noun_. If **The rumor that he escaped is false.** is a NP complement, why is **The way that he eats is amusing.** a relative clause? Or is this somehow different to the first sentence in my original post?

Comment: A Noun Phrase Complement is a _that_-clause that modifies and defines the content of a picture noun like _story_ or _report_. For instance, in _The rumor that he has quit is not true_, the clause _that he has quit_ is a complement clause modifying _rumor_. It's not a relative clause because it has no instance of the word _rumor_ in it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Two questions:
1) So is a Noun Phrase Complement a complement or not? Because after reading http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/that.html it seems there are only two types of complements (viz. subject and object) and they must be noun clauses rather than adjectival clauses.
2) Is _The way that he eats is amusing_ also an example of a Noun Phrase complement? Can "way" not also be a picture noun?

Comment: A noun complement is essentially the object complement of the verb that the picture noun is associated with. Like _the rumor that he has quit_ means _it is rumored that he has quit_, which is a verbal complement. Only nouns associated with some predicate like _story_ can take a complement clause. As to _way_, that's a relative clause, since it has a coreferent in the clause: _the way (that, *how) he eats_ comes from a clause like _he eats in `some` way_ that refers to manner. That's not true in noun phrase complements. There's no reference to _rumor_ in _that he has quit_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Can you firm the following? NP complement (_The rumor that..._) falls into the category of complement rather than relative clause:
1) Because there is no reference, so the part-of-speech of _that_ is a conjunction, rather than a relative pronoun.
2) Despite the fact that it's an adjectival clause, rather than a noun clause as complements usually are.
3) Despite the fact that the word _that_ is mandatory here, as opposed to being optional like the _that_ in an object complement. (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73320/without-that-clause/73368#73368)

Comment: To clarify my third point:
_The rumor **that** he has quit. (NP complement, mandatory)_ You explained that this can be re-written as the following to better see why it is a complement as opposed to a relative clause. _It is rumored **that** he has quit. (Object complement, optional)_ It makes me question the role of **_that_** in the first sentence, and whether it really is mandatory...

Comment: Sorry, just had another example I couldn't quite figure out:
_I am sure that he's fine._  So _am_ is a linking verb followed by the predicate adjective _sure_, and I'm guessing _that he's fine_ is a predicate nominative(?) In any case I don't see it falling into any of the four categories you mentioned.

Comment: _That he's fine_ is the complement of the predicate adjective _sure_. Any predicate can take a complement clause, and many predicate adjectives do, especially when concerned with emotions and mental processes. _Sure, certain, surprised,_ etc all work like that. _That_ is not mandatory in most clauses; it's an aid to parsing, and you don't need it every time. It's needed at the beginning of a sentence, to guide the parser down: _That he left early was too bad_ is ok, but not *_He left early was too bad._

Comment: @JohnLawler So then which of the four categories (object complement/subject complement/NP complement/relative complement) does _I am sure that he's fine._ fall into? Also it'd be cool if you could answer my earlier comments, thanks a lot!

Comment: Relative clauses are not complements (as I use the term, anyway). They're adjective clauses modifying an antecedent noun, not noun clauses functioning as subject or object. So there are not "four categories" (where do these exhaustive lists come from, anyway?); there are dozens of different kinds of clauses, depending on all kinds of variables.

Comment: @JohnLawler The categories come from this [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73368/15299) you gave me earlier. I thought the list exhaustive, so I've been trying to categorize instances of _that_ (as a conjunction/complementizer) into one of these. You keep emphasizing complements are noun clauses, yet in _The rumor that he's fine is false._, the **noun complement** is an adjectival clause. Likewise, in _I am sure that he's fine._ I don't know what you call it, maybe **adjective complement** (?) is also not a noun clause, but I'm guessing an adverbial clause, as it modifies _sure_.

Comment: @Joe: OK, hoist on my own petard, I see. It's not exhaustive. Those are not the only uses of _that_, of course -- only the ones that are complementizers, not demonstratives, for instance. It was _relative complement_ that threw me. The only adjective complement clause is an NP complement (and that's a very minor category, btw, because it's entirely determined by the noun, and there's only so many of those nouns). The clause _that he's fine_ does not modify _sure_, any more than a direct object modifies its verb. Adjective predicates can take complement clauses and often do.

Comment: @JohnLawler I know those aren't the only uses of _that_, but my point is that even only considering cases where _that_ is a complementizer, it's still not complete (so I don't know why you'd say **-- only the ones that are complementizers**). Case in point: _I am sure that he's fine._ doesn't belong to any of those categories. Even now I still don't know what the particular **name** nor the **nature** of _that he's fine_ other than that its a complement. By name I mean something like "NP Complement" or "Subject Complement"; by nature I mean something like "Adjective clause" or "Noun clause".

Comment: It's the complement of the predicate adjective. Adjectives can have complement clauses just like any other predicate. _I am certain/sure/unsure/troubled/upset/angry/glad that he's fine_, compare to _I think/believe/doubt/rejoice/said that he's fine_. Same thing, just a different variety of predicate.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, that was clear. Can the that-clause in _The belief that she is dead is true._ be viewed as an appositive instead of a noun complement? Why or why not? If not, is there any example of a that-clause acting as an appositive?

Comment: No. Because it's not an appositive. Those are noun phrases that are coreferential to preceding noun phrases (like _my son the guitarist_) and clausemates with them. They don't modify or complement anything. And clearly _the belief that she is dead_ has to be related to _`Indef` believes that she is dead_, so the complement of one is the complement of the other, and neither one is an appositive. Appositives are rare and easy to detect.

Comment: @JohnLawler On the subject of **Whiz deletion**, you said Whiz deletion works on both restrictive and non-restrictive relatives. So are these sentences grammatical then? 1) _I read the book, (which was) written by Alex._ 2) _Tom said he was ill, (which was) certainly true._

Comment: I never said it worked on **every** relative clause. There are other restrictions, plenty of them.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yeah I know that, but I meant to ask if these sentences are grammatically correct (in particular using Whiz deletion to form a participle phrase at the end of a sentence):
1) _I read the book, written by Alex._ 2) _I read the book, written by Alex, yesterday._