# Can anyone tell the function of "that" in the following sentence?

Tags: that

> The Mona Lisa is a beautiful painting. However, it was the mystery behind the painting ***that*** intrigued people.

In this sentence, can you identify what ***that*** is? Is ***that*** a relative pronoun or is the sentence a cleft sentence?

Comment: Cleft or not, traditional grammar classifies it as a relative pronoun, but modern grammar regards it as a subordinator.

Answer (score 2):

> - *It was the mystery behind the painting [that intrigued people].*

As pointed out, *that* introduces a relative clause which is part of a construction called an *It*-Cleft, a transformation that makes a complex sentence out of the simple sentence

- *The mystery behind the painting intrigued people.*

by converting the subject into a dummy existential clause and the verb phrase into a relative clause modifying the subject. Clefts of various sorts are quite common in English; they allow speakers to indicate the relative importance of various parts of a sentence (as the speakers perceive them).

The *that* is here a part of the cleft construction, but it could be swapped for a *wh*-pronoun *which*. That's a part of how relative clauses work. Why *that*? Well, *that* used to mark any tensed subordinate clause. There are three kinds of subordinate clauses by function

1. noun clauses like *(that) he left early* in *I'm glad (that) he left early.*
   These complement clauses have an optional *that* at the beginning.
2. adverbial clauses, which often have their own introducer, like *before*, as in
   *Before (that) we set up the tent, some of us thought we ought to eat.* This *that* is dialectal, [as shown in this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73368/15299), and represents an old construction, like the one Chaucer uses in *Canterbury Tales*. It's mostly not there any more in adverb clauses.
3. adjective clauses, which modify nouns, like NP Complements, e.g,
   *the rumor that the PM is a Martian*, where the *that* works like it does in noun clauses, as well as relative clauses, where it can take the place of a *wh*-pronoun, even though it's officially only a complementizer (or a subordinator) and doesn't have any referent like a pronoun ought to. Over the years it's become more and more common in relatives, for one reason because it can be used even where the *wh*-pronoun can't, like *the way (that/*how) he does it*.

This is all in addition to *that*'s role as a demonstrative pronoun (*this, that, these, those*). That's a busy word.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's very professional.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the relative clause is a modifier, since it doesn't combine with its antecedent to form a syntactic constituent. In my experience it is called a postnucleus, appearing at the end of the matrix clause.

Comment: In my experience relative clauses are called modifiers because they modify noun phrases.

Comment: Yes, but _it_ clefts are a special case where the relative clause is not a modifier but a postnucleus.

Comment: So in your terminology clefting converts the relative clause into a predicate? That's a reasonable interpretation of the function, but I don't see the need for a special term for components of clefts.

Comment: It's very good, this answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [BillJ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/141248/billj), since it is an answer:

> Cleft or not, traditional grammar classifies it as a relative pronoun, but modern grammar regards it as a subordinator.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very helpful.