# "She got used to that her life had changed" - Can a preposition take a content clause as complement?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, that

Can prepositions take content clauses as complement? For instance, are the sentences

> He did it by virtue of that he was annoyed

and

> She eventually got used to that her life had changed

grammatical?

I have definitely seen prepositions used in this way, but I cannot recall where.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, prepositions can definitely take content clauses as complements. HUDDLESTON & PULLUM'S *A Student's Introduction to
English Grammar* (pp. 175-176)  confirms:

> *Declarative content clauses* mostly function ***as complement of a*** verb,
> noun, adjective, or ***preposition***.
>
> - (1) You can go ***provided*** *[that you are careful]*.

The difficulty is that not all prepositions can accept a complement introduced by *that*. The same grammar book explains:

> ***That*** is inadmissible in a clause that is complement to a preposition like ***before***:
>
> - *I left *before* *that* he arrived.
>
> Most prepositions exclude *that*; there are only a very few (such as ***notwithstanding***,
> ***in order***, and ***provided***), which allow it. In (1) the content clause is complement of a preposition. As noted
> above, ***most prepositions disallow "that"***, but ***provided*** (historically derived from
> the past participle of a verb) is one of the few that allow it.

Neither ***of*** nor ***to*** allow for ***that*** clauses as their complements. I have tried to find proof for this affirmation, but unfortunately CAGEL does not include *of* or *to* in its list of prepositions governing *non-expandable content clauses* (which exclude *that*) - see p. 971. The list of those which can take expandable content clauses is more exhaustive and can be of use to understand more accurately how content clauses function as prepositional complements:

> but, in, save, considering, notwithstanding
>  seeing, except, now, so, given,
> provided
>  supposing, granted, providing

As a conclusion, your two examples are not grammatical. You can however save them, by adding ***the fact***:

> He did it by virtue of ***the fact*** that he was annoyed.
> <sub>*(intricate way of saying **He did it because he was annoyed**)*</sub>

and

> She eventually got used to ***the fact*** that her life had changed.

As @Araucaria - Not here any more. suggested in a comment, we could alternatively use a *[gerund-participial clause](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/is-a-gerund-participial-a-clause-adjunct-or-a-noun-adjective-post-modifier)*:

> He did it by virtue of ***his being annoyed***

and

> She eventually got used to ***her life having changed***.

Comment: +1 Note that not all declarative content clauses have *that*. The list of prepositions that don't allow *that* in H&P is actually a list of prepositions that ***do*** take content clauses, but not *expanded* content clauses. For example, the preposition *before* takes content clauses *I left before [he arrived]*. The prepositons *of* and *to* aren't on that list because, as you rightly say, they do *not* take content clauses at all. With or without *that*. :-)

Comment: Just a afterthought. Note that another way round this is to use a gerund participle clause. So for your two *the fact that* examples, we could alternatively say *He did it by virtue of his being annoyed* and *She eventually got used to her life having changed*.

Comment: Excellent comments, thanks for clarifying that. Your comment says it all and complements my answer, I don't think I need to edit it. I did think of the gerund, yes, one can use that too.

Comment: _That_ used to mark tensed clauses, like Chaucer's _Whan that Aprille hath .._, but now it's only used for relative clauses and NP complement clauses, not normally adverbial ones. Though in Andy Griffith's old routine [What it was, was football](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73368/15299) there's a _before that we set up the tent_ clause, with a _that_. That's authentic US rural dialect, but not standard.