# "I thought it was important that he say it in his own voice." – That he say it?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, verb-agreement, syntactic-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use the subjunctive mood?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood)

I have often come across constructions such as the one highlighted below and wondered how to explain the grouping of a third person singular subject with a plural verb.

> *I thought it was important that **he say** it in his own voice.*

My question is about the subject-verb agreement. If I'm not mistaken, the above sentence has two clauses: 1) *I thought it was important* 2) *that he say it in his own voice*

How does the subject in the second clause, *he*, agree with the plural verb *say*? Shouldn't it be *says* since *he* is the third person singular?

> Another example can be:
>
> *Personally, I'd recommend that **he speak** in public as soon as possible.*

I am curious to know how these constructions are not rare despite *seeming* ungrammatical.

Comment: Missed the duplicate because I didn't know to search for _subjunctive mood_.

Comment: They do not “seem ungrammatical”.  Not using them, however, does.