# "We propose the session focuses on ..." or "We propose the session focus on ..." Which is correct?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I understand a verb in English needs to match the sentence subject. Is the subject here "we" or "session", or am I seeing this incorrectly?

Comment: Both *we* and *session* are subjects.  A fuller rendition of the sentence is *We propose **that** the session focus on...*, with *that* marking the start of a new clause.  Since the verb *focus* is in the subjunctive mood here, it ought to be *focus*, not *focuses*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to tchrist, here is my answer.

This is a subjunctive sentence, as explained here:

[When should I use the subjunctive mood?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood)

So, the answer is "We propose that the session focus on ..."