# He drink only five liquids

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

while reading NYT's review on the Gladwell's last book I stumbled upon a rather strange passage:

> In the weeks I spent listening to Malcolm Gladwell’s podcast, I
>   learned that lobsters have serotonin, that Elvis Presley suffered from
>   parapraxis and that Mr. Gladwell adheres to a firm life rule that **he**
>   **drink** only five liquids: water, tea, red wine, espresso and milk.

Why the author uses "he drink" here? Is it a legal thing to do? Are there cases when you should use it?

Comment: It's simpler to consider the sentence << Jan sticks to the rule that she drink only water.>>

Comment: "Drink" is a plain form verb here, so the clause "that he **drink** only five liquids" is a subjunctive one. "Rule" is one of the nouns that licenses subjunctive clauses as complement.

Comment: Actually answered at [When should I use the subjunctive mood?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood/116698#116698); John Lawler lists _picture nouns derived from impositive predicates_ (including 'rule'!) licensing the subjunctive. The periphrastic should alternative is perhaps more common, at least in the UK (where the indicative is perhaps an even more common choice).

Comment: @amzin The meaning of subjunctives includes a component of meaning comparable to that expressed by the modal auxiliary "must". Compare "Mr Gladwell adheres to a firm life rule that he **drink** only five liquids" and  "Mr Gladwell adheres to a firm life rule that he **must drink** only five liquids".

Answer (score 1):

It's using the present subjunctive.

Examples:

-I'd like that *you be* quiet.

-He asked that *she come* early.

-Mary has a rule that *anyone visiting smoke* outside.

Comment: Well, yes, but that's just a name. It doesn't explain anything. It "uses the present subjunctive" because the _that_-clauses (the object clause of _would like_ and _asked_, and the noun complement clause of _rule_) require it. And the only thing they actually require is that the infinitive form of the verb be used (like I just did), instead of the normal present tense form. That's not a special mood, that's just an irregularity. You can only tell it's "subjunctive" in the third person singular: _I/you/they/we come early_ could swing either way.