# The use of was and were with singular nouns

Tags: grammar

"That's a very, very funny question given the time frame, would have been even funnier if it was a month in the future."

My friend corrected me, and said it should be "were a month in the future" Is that correct if both question and month are singular?

Comment: It's fine the way you said it. Your friend was probably thinking it should have been "subjunctive", which is a name some early grammarians used for a particular use of _were_ after _if_ instead of _was_ when speaking of an imaginary past. It's dying out, but you may encounter it here and there; don't use it unless you understand the grammar of it completely. You friend probably doesn't if they left you thinking this was about singular and plural number agreement.

Comment: I'm a fan of the subjunctive but as JL says, it's disappearing. In this case I might have said "if it had been a month...", depending on context.

Comment: Complementing Prof. Lawler's concise summary above is his [in-depth answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/116698/300) over on the question I'm closing this as a duplicate of.