# Doubt over a sentence with "require"

Tags: grammaticality

I'm co-writing a paper in which I have written the following sentence:

> Many applications of control theory require that the underlying system is controllable.

However, upon rereading, I think that the following might be the "more correct version".

> Many applications of control theory require that the underlying system be controllable.

Now that I look at both of these, neither seems correct and I'm not quite sure what the rule is here.  Is either of these options correct? Is either one better than the other?  Is there a way to rewrite this sentence so that it is less awkward?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: A slightly different version in the form of a question: are there any applications of control theory that *don't* require the underlying system to be controllable?

Comment: @WeatherVane For a trivial example: if you're looking at a system and trying to determine whether the system is controllable, that is technically an application of control theory to a non-controllable system.

Comment: But do you like my phrasing? *Many applications of control theory require the underlying system to be controllable.*

Comment: If you want to use a _that_ clause, an untensed one (with _be_) is preferred because of _require_. If you want to use an infinitive (there's no difference in meaning between the two with _require_), that's perfectly OK too. Author's choice.

Comment: ...Though in the UK, the untensed version would be used in a very formal register but 'is' in a less formal one (obviously, informal is unlikely here).

Comment: @WeatherVane Just seeing this now.  Actually, in the end I went with exactly that so that works

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/116698/300