# it is not inappropriate that risks be taken

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, subordinate-clauses

> Many outdoor experiences involve risk but that does not mean it is inappropriate that risks *be* taken, the report says.

(Source: [Stuff](http://www.stuff.co.nz/national/3531092/Gorge-to-reopen-two-years-after-tragedy), a New Zealand news media website)

I'm curious about the use of *be* here. Why use the subjunctive here? Is this a regional thing (down under) or something more universal?

Comment: The usage is discussed fully by J Lawler at [When should I use the subjunctive  mood/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood/116698#116698)  Most Brits would use either the indicative ('are') or the periphrastic ('should be') in such sentences; most Americans seem to prefer the ['what some people call the mandative ] subjunctive'.  I find the two halves of the sentence don't fit too comfortably; I'd prefer << 'Many outdoor experiences involve risk, but we can't start from the premise that **no** risks should be taken,' the report says. >>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The funny thing about the quote is that the subjunctive doesn't really carry any mandative force. So the theoretical question is whether you can use the subjunctive outside the mandative construction.

Comment: I would note in passing that the construction appears in a double-negative construction (_that does **not** mean it is **in**appropriate that..._), and therefore one is guaranteed syntactic fireworks.

Comment: It's, to quote JL, impositive (laying down a law or declaring freedom of action) ('It is wrong / not wrong that risks be taken'), so the terminology is arguably still applicable. However, 'mandative subjunctive' is a term far from universally accepted.

Comment: Clearly this is imposing conditions on somebody; the term _impositive_ is actually due to Georgia Green.

Comment: Whoever wrote that sentence should have their litotes license revoked.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you mean that _It is inappropriate that risks be taken._ cannot work as a standalone sentence?

Comment: Ho hum: Many outdoor experiences involve risk but that does not mean that **taking risks is inappropriate**, the report says. Why not rewrite it for the obvious meaning that is less awkward?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth FYI, Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar shows the term "mandative subjunctive", but not "impositive".

Comment: It's a term of art in linguistics, not the sort of thing one finds in dictionaries. It's a general term covering orders, requests, and indirect efforts to impose one's will on an addressee. Not all impositives are alike, but they all have a similar intended pragmatic effect.

Comment: @JK2 No, using _(in)appropriate_ in this context at all is clearly mandative. Someone is assuming authority to decide what kind of behavior is "appropriate" in their eyes, and to tell everyone about it. Certainly trying to influence people.

Comment: @JohnLawler Then why did you cite a double-negative construction?

Comment: And FYI, 'English has no subjunctive mood. ' [Bas Aarts, Author of the Oxford Modern English Grammar and the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar; May 2015] [[Grammarianism](https://grammarianism.wordpress.com/2015/05/21/does-english-have-a-subjunctive/)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't say 'English has a subjunctive mood'. And Bas Aarts said in the post, "In view of this it makes more sense to speak of _subjunctive clauses_ than of subjunctive verb forms." In OMEG, he does use the term "subjunctive" and "mandative subjunctive".

Comment: Is your hesitation about the subjunctive here based on the adjective *inappropriate* not seeming to be a subjunctive trigger? Or is it that it appears in a subclause (*that does not mean it is inappropriate that risks be taken*)? Does this standalone work for you? *It is inappropriate that risks be taken.*

Comment: Isn't this more about middle voice using a passive-like construction, rather than mandative? I would use this to distance myself from being the imposer - as in *hey, that's just the way things are*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "Is your hesitation about the subjunctive here based on the adjective _inappropriate_ not seeming to be a subjunctive trigger? Or is it that it appears in a subclause (_that does not mean it is inappropriate that risks be taken_)?" Definitely the former. // "Does this standalone work for you? _It is inappropriate that risks be taken._" It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as a whole is a stylistic train wreck. However, it doesn’t seem entirely out of the question to use the subjunctive here.

If we isolate the clause and take *to take* out of its passive form (*to be taken*), it becomes more defensible:

> *It is inappropriate that he take risks.*

(I’m using *he* as a stunt agent here so you can clearly see that *take* is in its bare, “subjunctive” form.)

Here it is back in context:

> *. . . that does not mean it is inappropriate that he take risks . . .*

And here it is back in the passive:

> *. . . that does not mean it is inappropriate that risks be taken . . .*

Compared with the “impositive” adjectives on John Lawler’s sample list,<sup>*</sup> *(in)appropriate* feels less subjunctive triggering to me.  Yet, *appropriate*’s synonym *okay* is on the list:

> *It is not okay that he take risks.*
> *It is not okay that risks be taken.*

*<sub>*acceptable*, *advisable*, *all right*, *appropriate*, *better*, *crucial*, *desirable*, *essential*, *expedient*, *fitting*, *imperative*, *important*, *legitimate*, *mandatory*, *necessary*, *okay*, *optional*, *permissible*, *preferable*, *right*, *satisfactory*, *sufficient*, *urgent*, and *vital*. Source: [When should I use the subjunctive mood? @JohnLawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood/116698#116698)</sub>

Here’s a more exhaustive list of alleged subjunctive triggers. This one includes *appropriate*:

[image: subjunctive triggers]

<sub>Source: [*The range of linguistic units: Distance effects in English mandative subjunctive constructions*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-linguistics/article/range-of-linguistic-units-distance-effects-in-english-mandative-subjunctive-constructions/E20DA767BD2107F88CCAAA51B84B2A21)</sub>

So I *could* buy *inappropriate* as a subjunctive trigger. In my American English, though, I think it would be an unlikely sale. This would be more natural:

> *. . . that does not mean it is inappropriate to take risks. . . .*

Comment: Thanks for citing the paper. That said, just as John Lawler did in his comment, you seem to presume that an antonym of an adjective that is a subjunctive trigger can automatically be a subjunctive trigger. What's the basis for the presumption? Does it sound natural to you to use the subjunctive after "unimportant" (antonym of "important") or "optional" (antonym of "imperative")? ? _It's unimportant/optional that he take risks._ Now, if that doesn't sound right, can it possibly be cured just by adding "That does not mean..."? ? _That does not mean it's unimportant/optional that he take risks._

Comment: If anything, adding *that does not mean* makes it sound less right. And we're talking about antonymy with *un-* or *in-* — not like *optional* / *imperative*. *It's unimportant that he take risks* is like *It's inappropriate that he take risks* — a hard sell as a subjunctive trigger. But *It's not important that he take risks* and *It's not appropriate that he take risks* sit better.

Comment: Agreed. Then, I think the presumption cannot be justified, and that you shouldn't be able to "buy _inappropriate_ as a subjunctive trigger".

Comment: *Involves* is certainly an impositive verb. Risk is being imposed on outdoor experiences. I suspect that the awkwardness of the sentence is causing some spillover of subjunctive triggers.  There are multiple senses of "appropriate", and I'm not sure all of them trigger the subjunctive.

Comment: @PhilSweet In any of the multiple senses of "appropriate", do you think there's a corresponding antonym "inappropriate" that triggers the subjunctive? If not, _it is inappropriate that he take risks_ shouldn't work.